# How to use BoxCoxTrans function in R?

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to use `BoxCoxTrans` function in R to resolve problem of skewness.

But, I have a problem that couldn't get result as data frame. This is my R code.

```
df<-read.csv("dataSetNA1.csv",header=TRUE)

dd1<-apply(df[2:61],2,BoxCoxTrans) #Except independent variable that located first column, All variables are numeric variable.

dd1
$LT1Y_MXOD_AMT
Box-Cox Transformation

96249 data points used to estimate Lambda

Input data summary:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       0       0   19594       0 1600000 

Lambda could not be estimated; no transformation is applied


$MOBL_PRIN
Box-Cox Transformation

96249 data points used to estimate Lambda

Input data summary:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       0  100000  191229  320000 1100000 

Lambda could not be estimated; no transformation is applied

str(dd1)
```

I don't know how to get result as data frame.

If I use `as.data.frame` function, this error message is posted.

```
dd2<-as.data.frame(dd1)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  클래스  ""BoxCoxTrans""를 data.frame으로 강제형변환 할 수 없습니다
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform a Box Cox transformation your data has to be positive. Hence, the values should be **greater than 0**.
The reason for this is, that the logarithm of 0 is -Inf.

If your data contains values of 0 you can just add 1 to each observation. This won't change your distribution/skewness.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to accomplish what you are after (I assume you are transforming the features):

```
library(caret)
data(cars)

#create a list with the BoxCox objects
g <- apply(cars, 2, BoxCoxTrans)

#use map2 from purr to apply the models to new data

z <- purrr::map2(g, cars, function(x, y) predict(x, y)) 

#here the transformation is performed on the same data on 
#which I estimated the BoxCox lambda for

B_trans = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, z)) #to convert to data frame

head(data.frame(B_trans, cars), 20)
#outpout

   speed       dist speed.1 dist.1
1      4  0.8284271       4      2
2      4  4.3245553       4     10
3      7  2.0000000       7      4
4      7  7.3808315       7     22
5      8  6.0000000       8     16
6      9  4.3245553       9     10
7     10  6.4852814      10     18
8     10  8.1980390      10     26
9     10  9.6619038      10     34
10    11  6.2462113      11     17
11    11  8.5830052      11     28
12    12  5.4833148      12     14
13    12  6.9442719      12     20
14    12  7.7979590      12     24
15    12  8.5830052      12     28
16    13  8.1980390      13     26
17    13  9.6619038      13     34
18    13  9.6619038      13     34
19    13 11.5646600      13     46
20    14  8.1980390      14     26
```

First two columns are transformed data and 2nd two are original data.

Another way is to incorporate the transformation of features during the training:

```
train(....preProcess = "BoxCox"...)
```

more on the matter: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-77/topics/train

Answer (score 0):

A BoxCox transformation is a transformation on your response variable. You could use the Boxcox function of the MASS package to find out what transformation is needed. Boxcox returns a lambda value. U should raise your response, say y, to the power lambda and this results in a new response variable, y*.
Then just replace the y-column in your old data frame by y*.

Note that if the resulting lambda is 0, you should apply a logarithmic transformation ln(y).